# Fiat-Shamir identification protocol

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am learning about the Fiat-Shamir protocol, which goes as follows. Let $n=pq$ be a public number, where $p$ and $q$ are unknown large prime numbers. Alice chooses a secret key $k\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and sends the public key $K=k^{2}$ to the verifier Bob. Then the protocol is:

1. Alice chooses a random $b\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and computes $a=b^{2}$. Alice sends $a$ to Bob.
2. Bob chooses a random $e\in\{0,1\}$ and sends this number to Alice.
3. Alice computes $x=bk^{e}$ and sends this to Bob.
4. Bob checks that $x^{2}=aK^{e}$.

My question is: why do we choose $k,b \in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ instead of in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security of the Fiat-Shamir protocol relies on the difficulty of computing square roots modulo large composite $n$ without knowing a factorization.

If  $\gcd(b,n)\ne 1$ or $\gcd(k,n)\ne 1$ an attacker would have a factorization of $n$ from $\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(b^2,n)$ or $\gcd(x,n)=\gcd(bk^e,n).$
This would allow to compute square roots $\bmod n$.